# Perl Module install error CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

When i try to install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel perl module using cpan in ubuntu 12.04, i get this following error.

```
> Can't exec "/usr/bin/make": No such file or directory at
> /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2078.  
> JMCNAMARA/OLE-Storage_Lite-0.19.tar.gz   /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
> 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state Running make
> test   Can't test without successful make Running make install   Make
> had returned bad status, install seems impossible Running make for
> J/JM/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz   Has already been
> unwrapped into directory
> /root/.cpan/build/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40-gJaT_A
> 
>   CPAN.pm: Going to build
> J/JM/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz
> 
> Warning: Prerequisite 'OLE::Storage_Lite => 0.19' for
> 'JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz' failed when processing
> 'JMCNAMARA/OLE-Storage_Lite-0.19.tar. 'make => NO'. Continuing, but
> chances to succeed are limited. Can't exec "/usr/bin/make": No such
> file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/Distribution.pm line
> 2078.   JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz   /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK Running make test   Can't test without successful make Running make install   Make had returned bad status, install seems
> impossible Failed during this command: 
> JMCNAMARA/OLE-Storage_Lite-0.19.tar.gz       : make NO 
> JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40.tar.gz : make NO
```

I tried the following changes also. It didn't work.

```
o conf make /usr/bin/make
o conf commit
```

Then i tried installing OLE-Storage_Lite, i got the same kind of error.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Look at the error message:

```
Can't exec "/usr/bin/make": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2078.
```

`make` is missing. Therefore: install `make`.

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Will get you most of what you need to compile software.

---

> I tried the following changes also

Those tell CPAN that it can find make at `/usr/bin/make`, the error message is already telling you that it doesn't exist there.

Comment: Maybe install will for most but I have make installed and I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

An easier alternative is probably:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libspreadsheet-writeexcel-perl
```

Comment: Is there a list published that 'translates' between the deb/apt package names and the CPAN ones? And any downside to doing it this way? What about mixing the two?

Comment: Not a list, but a rule. Convert the name to lower case, put 'lib' on the front of the name and '-perl' on the end.